# Animate surrounding with jquery UI slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to smoothly animate a div sliding out from the side and sliding another div out of the way using jquery and jquery ui. I can only seem to get the "other" div to snap to the new width but I can't seem to get it to "slide" to it. The sliding div has dynamic elements so I can't hardcode a value for .animate to run at the same time unless there is a method to get what the width of the original sliding element will be after showing/hiding, before doing so. regular jquery seems to have a progress function you can add in the options which could accomplish this, but this is removed in jquery ui (which I am using for the slide show/hide). Any suggestions?

What I wanted to work:

HTML:

```
<div id='expander'>
    <!-- dynamically set -->
</div>
<div id='header'>
    <img src='placeholder.png' />
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#expander").show("slide",{direction: "left", progress: function() {
    $("#header").width($("body").width()-$("#expander").width());
}});
```

css:

```
#header {
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    padding-left:600px;
    float:right;
    width:100%;
}

#expander {
    width:fit-content;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #176087;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    z-index:1;
    min-width:fit-content;
}
```

it doesn't because the slide option for show is only in the jQuery UI library, and the progress function option (calls every tick) is only in regular jQuery (jQuery UI function call doesn't support it).

Comment: Hello Connor, would you be able to add the code you're working with so that others can easily see what you're talking about? Your description would make more sense if we also got to see all of the relevant code.

Comment: @NickFriesen made that edit, hopefully this explains what I am trying to do a bit better

Comment: Thanks Connor, if you also have any CSS that goes along with this code that would help replicate the code so others can see exactly what you are currently doing and what you are trying to do.